# Shell script get email notification when the server is connected to internet

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal, sh

I want to check if a server has connected to the internet or not. I have tried following script unsuccessfully, which runs every 5 min and checks and sends an email if it is connected to internet.

```
 ping -c 3 192.168.0.25 > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
      mailx -s "Server is Up" -t "test@office.com" < /dev/null   
  fi
```

But problem is I will continuously get emails every 5 min once connection is established. How do I fix this?

Comment: What sort of notification do you want?

Comment: Preferably E-mail

Comment: But that's what you are doing! How do you want it to work differently?

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't want to be notified of a status but of a status change. So you have to remember somewhere what was the previous status, something like:

```
#! /bin/bash

statusFile=/var/tmp/connected # used to remember status
pingedHost=8.8.8.8
checkPeriod=5 # seconds

while true
do
    echo "Sleeping..."
    sleep $checkPeriod
    echo "Checking..."
    ping -c 1 $pingedHost > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
    then
        echo "Ping OK..."
        if [[ ! -f $statusFile ]] # not connected already
        then
            echo "Reconnected..."
            # send reconnection mail here
            touch $statusFile # remember state
        fi
    else
        echo "Ping KO..."
        if [[ -f $statusFile ]] # was connected before
        then
            echo "Disconnected..."
            # send disconnection mail here
            rm $statusFile # remember state
        fi
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be better to check if result is zero rather than an -e, right?

```
if [$? -eq 0]
```

Or this

```
if [$? -e 0]
```

is just a typing error?

Comment: Sorry, It's a typo